# Give a "Sorry I don't understand that" result from chatbot If the chatbot doesn't understand a user message

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, chatbot

I am using the chatterbot Python library to create a Flask chatbot. The chatbot is actually working fine but If I send a message like say for example some random jibberish It either ignores It or asks me another question or doesn't give an answer.

How do I make It so that the chatbot replies "Sorry I don't understand that" If the user sends a message that It does not understand?

I am using the chatterbot corpus which is built in inside the chatterbot library and Here's my code so far:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer

app = Flask(__name__)

chatbot = ChatBot("chatbot_name")

bot = ChatBot(
    'chatbot_name',
    storage_adapter='chatterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter',
    database_uri='sqlite:///database.sqlite3'
)

bot = ChatBot(
    'chatbot_name',
    logic_adapters=[
        'chatterbot.logic.BestMatch',
        'chatterbot.logic.TimeLogicAdapter'],
)

trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(chatbot)

trainer.train(
    "chatterbot.corpus.english"
)

@app.route('/')

def home():
    return render_template('bot1.html')

@app.route('/get')
def get_bot_response():
    userText = request.args.get('msg')
    return str(chatbot.get_response(userText))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried checking the value of `chatbot.get_response(userText)` - presumably this is empty for non-recognized sentences, so you could check for `“”` or `None` and give your `‘what did you say?’` response instead.

Comment: @barny Oh never thought in that way. Let me try.

Comment: @barny Nope. That did not work but in the past days, I managed to find another solution as well so I'll It myself.

Comment: But a quick peruse of the chatterbot documentation doesn’t seem to show it can give an indication of quality of match for the returned response, which TBH seems odd, but anywway maybe you can provide your on comparison function which is a wrapper around whichever inbuilt comparison function you’re using and which would remember the returned value somewhere you can access it, then it returns that value. Useful, reading the documentation; see https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/comparisons.html - but anyway it’s all there in Python source code for you to adapt/extend. Have a look.

Comment: What does “That did not work” mean exactly; i.e. why didn’t it work?

Comment: @barny I am not sure why it didn't work. Probably because of the fact that the get_response default value is not empty rather null or undefined or maybe something else, I am not sure. But what I am sure about is that I found a working solution in my answer below.

What do you think about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution. After looking at the source code of the chatterbot library I found out that each reply that the chatterbot gives has Its own `confidence` that is a `Float` value between 0 and 1.

If the `confidence` equals 0, then the chatbot did not understand It so the response should be "Sorry I do not understand that"

and If the `confidence` equals 1, then the chatbot should return the response. So this is what I came up with.

```
def get_bot_response():
    userText = request.args.get('msg')
    if chatbot.get_response(userText).confidence < 0.5:
        return str("Sorry I do not understand that.")
    else:
        chatbot.get_response(userText).confidence = 1
        return str(chatbot.get_response(userText))
```

and It seems to work pretty well now.

Comment: Looks like you could call `chatbot.get_response(userText)` just once, save it in a variable